# C++ New line character when outputting to a text file

Tags: c++, file, newline, output

This is just a quick question. But I am trying to output data to a file, which works fine.
However I am also trying to implement a new line at the appropriate point so the data, prints on individual lines.

This is how my code currently looks:

main.cpp

```
Writer w("Output.txt");
    w.writeString("The number of words in the script are: ");
    w.writeInt(count);
    w.writeEol();
    w.writeString("The number of Officers in the script are: ");
    w.writeInt(ofCount);
    w.writeEol();
    w.writeString("The number of Courtiers in the script are: ");
    w.writeInt(cCount);
        w.close();
```

Writer.cpp

```
void Writer::writeEol()
{
    out << "\n" << endl;
}
```

My code has to be implemented this way as my whole system is built around it like this.

So my question is, how would I adjust my Writer::writeEol() to add a new line to my output file?

My output file currently comes out like this:

```
    The number of words in the script are: 32339The number of Officers in the script are: 2The number of Courtiers in the script are: 9
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Well, you have the code for `writeEol`. What isn't working?

Comment: What is `out`? How do you declare and initialize it? How do you view the output file?

Comment: you should also show us how the `out` stream has been opened, and what platform/OS are you working with. It looks like a binary/text translation mismatch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without a proper question I can just guess what you're trying to learn, so feel free to update your "question" with an actual question:

You're essentially writing two line breaks into the file, depending on the encoding (i.e. Windows or Unix line breaks) you won't see the difference:

`std::endl` will automatically include the correct character to create a linebreak. There's no need to write `"\n"` as well.

Also you don't have to pass `std::endl` to the stream unless you really want a line break at the specific position:

```
std::cout << "The result is: ";
std::cout << 50 << std::endl;
```

Keep in mind that depending on your editor you might not see all line breaks, e.g. Windows Notepad won't show a line break with only `\n`. It will instead appear as an invisible character. For actual line breaks that are accepted you'd beed `\r\n`. In comparison, the Open Source editor Notepad++ accepts and displays both kinds of line breaks.

Comment: I'm confused by your last sentence. The only difference between `std::endl` and `\n` is a flush.

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem. :)

Comment: @chris: Judging by the code for `writeEol()` above, I assumed James thinks `std::endl` will just flush or somehow end the cout line, because he writes `"\n"` AND `std::endl`, which doesn't make any real sense to me if you just want a single line break/EOL.

Comment: Possibly worth pointing out that there _could_ be a performance gain by using `\n` in place of `std::endl`, as you wouldn't be forcing a flush each line. How much of an effect his has is debatable, mind.

Comment: Not wrong at all, especially when writing console programs. At least under Windows flushing is still very slow on console output. But for writing files I doubt it's really noticeable, considering properly set up write caches etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your `writeEol()` method, you output both a newline (`\n`), and you write out a `std::endl`.  These both have the effect of writing out a newline, which is what you want.  However, the `std::endl` will also flush the stream, which in some cases is not desireable (it could cause slowdown if the stream is flushed after every line).

I think that your code will do what you want (albeit with two newlines), but as shuttle87 states, you only need a `\n` at the end of each line to achieve the desired affect.