# New line is not working with files in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io, turbo-c++

And i know that this question is already asked by some other user. Yes it is duplicated and here is the [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373766/adding-a-newline-to-file-in-c) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415833/c-new-line-character-when-outputting-to-a-text-file) . I tried every solutions given in the link but still its not working. I am using TurboC++ 4.5 compiler from borland .  And here is my code

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream.h>

int main()
{
  ofstream fout;

  fout.open("COUNTRY");
  fout<<"UNITED STATES OF AMERICA \n";
  fout<<"UNITED KINGDOM \n";
  fout<<"SOUTH KOREA \n";
  fout.close();

  fout.open("CAPITAL");
  fout<<"WASHINGTON \n";
  fout<<"LONDON \n";
  fout<<"SEOUL \n";
  fout.close();

  const int N=80;
  char line[N];
  ifstream fin;

  fin.open("COUNTRY");
  cout<<"\nCONTENTS OF COUNTRY FILE\n";
  while(fin)
  {
    fin.getline(line,N);
    cout<<line;
  }
  fin.close();

  fin.open("CAPITAL");
  cout<<"\nCONTENTS OF CAPITAL FILE\n";
  while(fin)
  {
    fin.getline(line,N);
    cout<<line;
  }
  fin.close();

  return 0;
}
```

I checked for more solutions but can't resolve this issue and that's why i am posting it here.

Comment: Try using a debugger and put a breakpoint after the `getline`.  Look at your `line` variable.  Verify that it has a newline **and a terminating null character**.

Comment: What isn't working?  There are no newlines in the file?  What editor are you using to view them?  Have you tried `\r\n`?  Why are you using such an old compiler?

Comment: @RetiredNinja . yeah i tried using \r\n . but no use . Can i resolve the issue if i change the compiler.

Comment: First I think you need to explain exactly what is wrong.  Are there no newlines in the file you write?  Is it a display problem when you are reading the file back?  `getline` should read all of the characters up to the delimiter, in this case `\n`, and discard the delimiter.  If that is the case then you need to add a `\n` to the end of the lines you read when you print them.

Comment: this code is older than I am

Comment: Your compiler is from two decades ago. _From before C++ was standardised._ Get a new one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit . yeah i changed the compiler brother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use 'endl' instead of '\n'

check this link: [C++: "std::endl" vs "\n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a newline character when you write your data out. Reading it in with `getline` discards the "\n" at the end of each line.

> If the delimiter is found, it is extracted and discarded, i.e. it is
>   not stored and the next input operation will begin after it.

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) is the page that the preceding quote is from.

So the problem is that you are storing null-terminated strings that do not end with "\n".